# How to generate appropriate distance matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For reasons of computational chemistry I was trying to generate a point cloud from an Euclidean distance matrix. The idea is that I generated the matrices from a small set of features (real numbers) and then I could obtain the geometry of the point cloud from that matrix.

I am not sure what to use as features just yet, however, I began fiddling with algorithms for making the transition from a distance matrix to a point cloud and I found that it was much more of a problem than I had anticipated.

By looking for ways out of the hole I had dub myself in, I stumbled upon [this post on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725693/how-to-generate-a-distance-matrix-from-the-height-function-applied-on-the-point) which proposes an interesting algorithm using what he calls a Gram Matrix. They have also provided what appears to be [the original paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999178900815) which I *think* explains the same thing, but in a more rigorous way.

So the method is as follows. We need to construct the Gram matrix for the distance matrix $\mathbf{D}$. The Gram matrix $\mathbf{G}$ can be written element-wise as shown in eq. $(1)$.
$$
\tag{1}
G_{ij} = \frac{D^2_{1j}+D^2_{i1}-D^2_{ij}}{2}
$$
In order to obtain the point cloud that generated the distance matrix you then need to diagonalize the Gram matrix, which will give you the diagonal eigenvalue and column eigenvector matrices, respectively $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ shown in eq. $(2)$.
$$
\tag{2}
\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{V}^\mathrm{T} 
$$
With the Gram eigenvalues and eigenvectors we can now construct the $\mathbf{\Xi}$ matrix like so:
$$
\tag{3}
\mathbf{\Xi} = \mathbf{V}\sqrt{\mathbf{S}}
$$
Since $\mathbf{S}$ is a diagonal matrix, its matricial square-root is simply an elemente-wise application of the normal square root along its main diagonal elements, so it is pretty trivial to calculate.

Now here is the trick. If the data is to be embedded in a $k$-dimensional space, in our case we want $k=3$, then only $k$ columns of $\mathbf{\Xi}$ will be non-zero and the subset of $\mathbf{\Xi}$ that has non-zero columns is $\mathbf{X}$, our solution. In a very non-mathematical way we could write that:
$$
\tag{4}
\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{\Xi}[:,1:k]
$$
At first I thought that any real positive symmetric matrix with zero diagonal elements would do but no. The method only works for real data if the Gram matrix has positive eigenvalues, otherwise the square roots in eq. $(3)$ will yield imaginary numbers.

I'm not sure what the problem is just yet, but I found a promising candidate. It turns out that although any real positive symmetric matrix with zero diagonal elements could represent a dissimilarity matrix of data points under the Euclidean norm, it does not necessarily represent a *distance* matrix of points in space.

For that, the elements of $\mathbf{D}$ must obey the relationship shown in eq. $(5)$, called *The Triangle Inequality*.
$$
\tag{5}
D_{ij} ≤ D_{ik} + D_{kj}
$$
So **Here is my question:**

> Is there a general algorithm for the generation of *distance* matrices? Matrices that have real positive Gram eigenvalues and for which the elements respect the triangle inequality.

#### Edit 1

I realized how tautological my question seemed and decided that I had poorly phrased it.

In response to a comment from Jean Marie: I am aware that SVD could be used for MDS, however reducing the dimensionality is no issue, here. If the distance matrix is valid, then the Gram diagonalization works as intended.

The problem is *generating* the distance matrix in the first place. I am working with a particular project in computational chemistry in which I am required to generate valid distance matrix from simpler objects. I had originally envisioned these objects as the eigenvalues of the distance matrix with random orthogonal eigenvectors but that did not pan out. These simple objects I called *features*.

Eigenvalues as features did not work out because there is no simple relationship between the eigenvalues of a distance matrix and all of its properties, in particular the triangle inequality.

It would be nice if the generation could be done *without* the generation of a point cloud, but rather through some other method like this one.

Comment: Random with respect to what probability distribution? I mean one way to do it would be to take a random (with respect to some distribution) set of points in dimension $k$ and then calculate the distance matrix of that point-set, but that would seem to circumvent your particular application...

Comment: @DanRust Right, so that would be a non-useful way to do it. It is nice to test it, but not so nice to apply it for the problem at hand.

Comment: Shouldn't you consider the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) instead of the "ordinary" diagonalisation (2) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know. Should I? xD. What is the reasoning behind that assertion? I'm all ears.

Comment: See [MDS : MultiDimensional Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) which uses Principal Components Analysis, a cousin of the SVD decomposition.